# Use pandas to append a .xslx file is overwriting it?

Tags: pandas

I have a very simple code and I cannot figure out why it isn't working. Consider the dataframes below,

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[3,4]})
test2 = test1+3
```

I would like to export these into two separate sheets in an excel spreadsheet so I wrote the code

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(path+'.xlsx',mode='W') as writer:
    test1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1')

with pd.ExcelWriter(path+'.xlsx',mode='A') as writer:
    test2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet2')
```

where the path is just a string to the folder. Running this returns a single spreadsheet labeled 'Sheet2' and has the data from table2. Evidently it overwrote it and didn't append it. Why? How can I solve this?

Of course I can write

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(path+'.xlsx',mode='W') as writer:
    test1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1')
    test2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet2')
```

which will generate a spreadsheet with both sheet1 and sheet2 and the data stored properly, but I would like to get this append to work because I am trying to generalize to many more dataframes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by many more dataframe. The last piece of code seems to work for any number of dataframe. Just don't close the writer when you are not done writing?

Comment: what happens if you use a lower case "a" for your second `mode`?

Comment: throws the errror "ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!"

Comment: This code is within a for loop where I am creating temporary dataframes and then exporting them immediately with a condition that the first dataframe has mode='W' and all other ones mode = 'A'

Comment: oh, try using openpyxl instead

Comment: The error just said you can't append with `xlsxwriter`, try to change the engine. That said, in your case just put `with pd.ExcelWriter` outside of the `for` loop and you're good to go.

Comment: It only says that error with the lowercase "a" not the uppercase one. In the uppercase "A" there is no error but I think it must be the case that mode='A' does not actually append, correct? I mean given this simple code where it is overwriting rather than appending it must be broken right?